# How to fix Items position in react native flex layout?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using **flex layout** for my react native project. When I run my app on the device and change the phone language to Persian(RTL) my layout direction changes with that but I don't want to change it. So I'm looking for a way to set my directions to fix or choose them by phone language dynamically.
something like this:

```
if (lang===persian){
  flexDirection : 'row-reverse'
}
else{
  flexDirection : 'row'
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use NativeModules and Platform:

```
import { NativeModules, Platform } from 'react-native'

//OS
const isIOS = Platform.OS === 'ios';

// lang:
const lang = isIOS ? NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale : NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier;

[...]

<View style={[
     somestyle, //var containing your style
     lang === 'yourlanguage' ? {flexDirection : 'row-reverse'} : {flexDirection : 'row'} ]} // if presian change flexdirection
/>
```